# COUNT() function and SELECT with DISTINCT on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

Hoping someone can help me figure why I'm getting a syntax error here. I'm counting all rows that have two distinct column values.

```
select count (*) as 'Distinct' from (
    select distinct p.IDD, p.num
    from PERF1 p
    inner join MAST1 m
    on (m.id_table = p.id_table and m.SOURCE_TABLE = p.SOURCE_TABLE)
    where m.DATE > '2012-12-31' )
```

I'm getting an error on my last close bracket but can't for the life of me figure what I'm doing wrong here.
...............................

Kind of a huge "edit" but I'm a bit stuck. I thought that this query would count the number of distinct rows (for both columns) across this table. So for instance the count should return 6 since "P" and "T" are repeated. I thought I had it with this:

```
select count (*) as 'Distinct' from (
select distinct p.IDD, p.co
from PERF1 p
inner join MAST1 m
on (m.id_table = p.id_table and m.SOURCE = p.SOURCE)
where m.DATE > '2012-12-31' ) TempTable
```

but I'm getting a much higher number than I think I should so I'm hoping that my query is incorrect.

```
+------+------+
| IDD  | CO   |
+------+------+
| 11   | P    |
| 12   | P    |
| 13   | T    |
| 14   | T    |
| 15   | R    |
| 16   | S    |
| 17   | U    |
| 18   | K    |
```

Comment: Just add a letter `a` after the last closing bracket

Comment: Glad to help. MySQL wants an alias for your temp sub-query

Comment: Also, the single quotes around the column alias `Distinct` (on the first line of the query) should be replaced with backtick characters. (That alias has to be "escaped" because it is a MySQL reserved word; as an alternative, consider using a different alias, one which is not on the [**MySQL Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) list .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a alias name for the subquery

```
select count (*) as 'Distinct' from (
    select distinct p.IDD, p.num
    from PERF1 p
    inner join MAST1 m
    on (m.id_table = p.id_table and m.SOURCE_TABLE = p.SOURCE_TABLE)
    where m.DATE > '2012-12-31' ) TempTable
```

Comment: +1 Without an alias assigned to the subquery referenced in the FROM clause, MySQL should be issuing an error with a message akin to "every derived table must have an alias". Also, the single quotes around `Distinct` in the first line should be replaced with backtick characters.

Comment: As you IDD column is unique in the list you mentioned, you are getting a the rows, select only distinct for the column co

Comment: @Rajesh what if column IDD isn't unique, will it select values with distinct values in both IDD and CO?

Comment: @midiman the discinct will check for unique value combination of IDD and CO. in this case  13 , T and 14, T are distinct so both will be reported , but you wanted to report only once in that case need to select only CO and if you want IDD, you need to get top 1 out of this i.e. you might get 13 or 14 for IDD and T for CO